# Recursive N-knightsproblem

Tags: c++, c, recursion, n-queens

I am trying to solve a n-knights problem on an 8x8 chessboard recursively. The n-knights problem is a variation of the n-[queens problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), where the queens are replaced by knights. No piece can take another piece.

My code so far: http://pastebin.com/TVza3jVU.

The input consists of the number of knights that have to be placed on the chessboard. My code prints a lot of correct boards

Output looks like this (example):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  5
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0  6
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0  7

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

nrBoards = 49
```

A '1'  stands for a knight.

---

My problem is as follows:

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0  0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  6
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  7

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This is the last board my script will print. It will never put a knight on [0][0]. I can not figure out why. It also skips some configurations. Is there something wrong with my recursion?

Comment: Can you post the code here, rather than linking elsewhere?

Comment: Introduction to Computer Science?

Comment: Sounds like a question which is better asked in [programmers stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)!?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have linked, it seems that one problem is in your checkplace() function. You do not check whether the bounds of x+2, x-2, y+2, y-2 etc are in or out of the interval 0 to 7.

```
int checkPlace(int y, int x, chessboard boards) {
    if (boards.board[y - 2][x - 1] == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y - 1][x - 2] == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y - 2][x + 1] == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y - 1][x + 2] == 1) {      
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y + 1][x + 2] == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y + 1][x - 2] == 1) {      
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y + 2][x - 1] == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (boards.board[y + 2][x + 1] == 1) {
      return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Instead:

```
if ( x-1 >= 0 && y-2 >= 0 && boards.board[y - 2][x - 1] == 1) {
```

Similarly for others.